# Blank Screen after login Ubuntu 18.04 no desktop

Tags: gnome

I am getting a getting blank screen and no desktop after logging in putting in the right credentials. I force restarted my laptop once as it was stuck after sleep and from then on I am just getting that black screen after login. Terminal interface works fine. 
Ubuntu 18.04 Nvidia drivers

Answer (score 0):

I just did an upgrade from Lubuntu 16.?? to Lubuntu 18.04. My symptoms were a blank screen and visible/movable mouse cursor. I could get to my desktop by switching to vt1 (ctrl-alt-F1) and switching back to vt7 (alt-F7). My issue was an xrandr command in .xprofile which worked on the earlier version of Lubuntu, but not on 18.04. I commented out the that line in .xprofile and all returned to normal.

Comment: Was the command something that you had added to .xprofile yourself, or something that you believe was a remnant from the earlier installation?  You should also consider adding the commands and directories in which the files are found - but welcome to AskUbuntu!